# multiline equation preview sublime

Tags: math-mode, equations, preview, sublime-text

The preview works just fine for any single line equation.
However, it does not work for multiline equations.
Is there any solutions or work around?

I am writing math derivation so having the preview would help me a lot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

test multiline
\begin{align}
\left\vert\frac{v_{out}}{i_{in}}\right\vert^2 = & 
\frac{(1 + g_{m1}r_{o1})^2R^2_{1}}
     { (\omega C_{IN}(r_{o1}+ R_{1} ))^2 + (g_{m1}r_{o1} + 1)^2 } \\
\approx &
\frac{(1 + g_{m1}r_{o1})^2R^2_{1}}
     { (\omega C_{IN}(r_{o1}+ R_{1} ))^2 + (g_{m1}r_{o1})^2 + 1 }
\label{eq:tf_magnitude}
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

There is preview for single line equation but not for any multiline equation.
[image]

Comment: Please provide code and more information about what exactly you are doing, which is not particularly clear from the question in its current form.